# Set up single event handler for multiple buttons in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

An application I'm writting in silverlight/c# consists of 13 permanent buttons that when clicked perform a simple navigation to another page.

The problem is my code behind has 13 different event handlers(alot of code) for a nearly identical purpose.

Is there a way to detect which button was pressed so that a single event handler gets fired, and a simple if statement within could determine which page to go to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes: you can use the same method for all buttons, and use the parameter "sender" as "sender.Name" to get the name of the pressed button.

Answer (score 2):

In the designer code of your program, tack on the same event handler for all 13 buttons (look for the code that has += and put the same event handler for all of them).

Notice that the event handler has an object (s) parameter. You can use this parameter as follows:

```
if(s.Name = "Button1") {//button 1 stuff}

else if (s.Name = "Button2") {button 2 stuff}
```

etc..

EDIT: should have been s.Name = "Button1, 2, 3, etc.."

Answer (score 1):

Test the sender parameter of the button click event handler - you'll be able to test which button was the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary using 'sender' as key. The 'value' could be the page to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of code in your event handler you should break that out to a separate method anyway and send the button specific parameters to that method.

But you can still have one event handler if you look at the sender argument.